# How to unit test function that calls Amplify Api mutate method?

Tags: kotlin, graphql, mockito, aws-amplify

I have a system that is using Amplify Api to interact with a GraphQL api that is not part of an Amplify project. None of it was set up with the `amplify-cli`. I have a function that makes a call to the `mutate` function of the `AmplifyCategory` class. I would like to unit test my function, making sure to test both callbacks of the `mutate` method. How can I mock the `mutate` method to tell it which callback to use, and test that the callback was, in fact, called?

MyClass.kt

```
import com.amplifyframework.api.ApiCategory
import com.amplifyframework.api.aws.GsonVariablesSerializer
import com.amplifyframework.api.graphql.SimpleGraphQLRequest

class MyClass {
    private val graphQlClient: ApiCategory = [... do stuff to configure client]

    suspend fun foo(): Boolean {
        val mutationDefinition = """
            mutation doFoo {
              doFoo
            }""";
        try {
            val mutation = SimpleGraphQLRequest<Boolean>(mutationDefinition, Boolean::class.java, GsonVariablesSerializer())
            var success: Boolean = false
            graphQlClient.mutate(mutation,
                {
                    success = it.data
                },
                {
                    logger.error("ERROR!")
                }
            )
            return success
        } catch (e: Throwable) {
            logger.debug("unexpected error $e")
            throw e
        }
    }
}
```

TestMyClass.kt

```
import com.amplifyframework.api.ApiCategory
import com.amplifyframework.api.graphql.GraphQLOperation
import com.amplifyframework.api.graphql.GraphQLRequest
import com.amplifyframework.api.graphql.GraphQLResponse
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.async
import kotlinx.coroutines.delay
import kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking
import org.junit.Test
import org.mockito.kotlin.any
import org.mockito.kotlin.doReturn
import org.mockito.kotlin.mock
import org.mockito.kotlin.stub
import org.mockito.kotlin.verify

class TestMyClass {
    [A bunch of stuff to initialize...]
    private val mutationResult by before {
        GraphQLResponse(true, null)
    }

    private val graphQlOperation by before {
        mock<GraphQLOperation<Boolean>>()
    }

    private val mockGraphQlClient by before {
        mock<ApiCategory>().stub {
            on { mutate(any<GraphQLRequest<Boolean>>(), any(), any()) } doReturn graphQlOperation
        }
    }

    private val client by before {
        MyClass()
    }

    @Test
    fun `foo() should return true when mutate succeeds`() = runBlocking<Unit> {
        val deferredResult = async(Dispatchers.IO) {
            client.foo()
        }
        deferredResult.start()

        delay(500L)

        val result = deferredResult.await()
        result shouldBe true // Fails here, presumably because the success lambda never gets invoked

        verify(mockGraphQlClient).mutate(
            any<GraphQLRequest<Boolean>>(),
            any(),
            any()
        )
    }
}
```

I've tried a few different things that have not worked, including using Mockito's `whenever` on the `mutate` function to try to invoke the second argument, but that fails because the lambda cannot be case to a `GraphQlOperation`

```
whenever(mockGraphQlClient.mutate(any<GraphQLRequest<Boolean>>(), any(), any())).thenAnswer {
    it.arguments[0].success()
}
```

`Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class arrow.core.Try$Success cannot be cast to class com.amplifyframework.api.graphql.GraphQLOperation (arrow.core.Try$Success and com.amplifyframework.api.graphql.GraphQLOperation are in unnamed module of loader 'app')`

I've also tried using an `argumentCaptor` to capture the arguments being passed to `mutate`, but I can't verify that they've been called because they aren't mocks.

With all of these cases, I'm pretty sure the lambdas are not actually being invoked. Any help would be greatly appreciated.